# program error exceptions shouldn't be caught by application program

Tags: java, exception

I'm learning java and I don't understand
Why should the program error exception never be caught by the application program?

Comment: Can you provide a source for where you read that? Are you talking about an *exception* or an *error*? These are two distinct concepts. I assume it is about the latter -- `java.lang.error`? If so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017304/catching-java-errors

Comment: Your question doesn't include enough detail to answer. Who says and in what context?

Comment: Can you post the exact quote you found? I have no clue what you mean by "program error exceptions". If you mean system exceptions, like `OutOfMemoryError`, they should only be caught in certain circumstances, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Why should the program error exception never be caught by the application program?

You should only catch Exception/Errors at the point when you can handle and recover from them.  `Error`s are usually too serious to be able to handle and recover from. Never the less, you can catch them in rare case, esp if you want to log them.