# How can I find out why my app crashes if logcat show no reason?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an app that processing some pdf files in background and suddenly it crashes with no 'caused by' description. Tried with real devices, new emulators, restarted pc and so on. [image]
Never had something before and I don't know where to search for the root cause.

### Edit: I found that problem was in a try/catch block

```
try {
val pdfReader = PdfReader(URL(it))
//process
pdfReader.close()
} catch(e: FileNotFoundException){
//process exception
}
```

So the problem was in wrong exception, when I switched to a more general exception, I could handle it and see error in logcat

```
try {
val pdfReader = PdfReader(URL(it))
//process
pdfReader.close()
} catch(e: Exception){
//process exception
}
```

Comment: Try debugging .

Comment: I tried, but no exceptions caught

Comment: Are you using some third party library or handing over some operation for the third party library to handle. Can you try to debug and find if that entry and exit from the library is smooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using iTextPdf it can sometimes throw NoClassDefFoundError for no reason as far as i have experienced. Maybe catching this Error instead of Exceptions could help you identify the problem. Like this:

```
try
{
  // do stuff
}
catch (Error err) //or NoClassDefFoundError
{
  System.err.println(err.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: This is not solution to my question, but it was a clue for me, the problem was in a try catch block, I will edit my question to provide solution. Thank you!

Comment: You should NEVER catch `Error`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11018879/6296561 -- A NoClassDefFoundError is an indicator of a severe problem at compile time that you need to fix. Not catch, ignore, and pretend it doesn't exist. _Fix._

Comment: You are both right, an error is not meant to be caught and my solution was not a solution. It was a suggestion because i have had this kind of problem before. If there is a class not found error, you should really look into that library or the android os itself.