How to report a StackOverflowError without triggering another StackOverflowError?
I have the following situation:
I have code that is prone to StackOverflowErrors. This will have to be rewritten eventually, but for now, it is important that it is reporting the condition reliably before it dies.
Thing is, creating an error message and submitting it into the logging framework itself needs stack space. Possibly considerable amounts of stack space; I had a noteworthy situation when the stack overflowed before all classes needed for logging were loaded, so another stack overflow happened inside the class loader, obscuring the original stack overflow.
Note that these crashes can and do happen in situation where it's desirable that the software continues to run.
My current situation is unit tests, where some tests could overflow the stack (and in fact are expected to) but I still want to see the results of other tests.
Another conceivable situation would be a server that hits a stack overflow; it should not need a restart just because one of several requests being processed ran into a stack overflow.
I can imagine various ways to deal with this, but is there a discussion of the various approaches, how they work in practice, and what JVM guarantees they can rely on?
E.g. does the JVM guarantee some reserve stack space on StackOverflowError, and if yes, where's the specification?

Sure you want to catch Error instances? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352780/when-to-catch-java-lang-error and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017304/catching-java-errors suggest you shouldn't. This sounds like an XY problem.

Yes, I am sure. I'm rewriting the situation description so it's clearer why the situation is relevant and needs a solution other than "just let it crash".

@Progman actually I find the linked questions to list quite some exceptional situations where catching errors is the right thing to do, such as knowing the exact error that will happen and how to deal with it, multithreaded servers, and post-mortem reporting. "Never catch Errors" is just wrong, unless it comes with an "unless".

‘It is important that it is reporting the condition reliably before it dies’: why? It would be better to catch it at the invoker, so that all the recursion or whatever is causing it has unwound, in which case logging will be perfectly safe.

There are some types of errors that can not be handled. These can be OutOfMemory or StackOverflow, there is literraly nothing you can do. If you want to make  tests that handles StackOverflow, then make a condition in which this exception will be thrown, for instance throw it explicitly if there is overflown a half of stack. If the program overflows a half of stack, then it is high probability there will be a stack overflow anyway. But, how to do it? I have no idea.y

@armagedescu That’s not correct. When you catch a StackOverflowError at the origin of a recursion the stack is fully unwound. The problem comes when you try to catch it on every recursion. So don’t do that.

Just let the StackOverflowError unwind the stack, and report it from the first nonrecursive function that is calling into the recursion. Thanks to user207421 for the idea, it's very clean and actually what I'd consider the go-to solution.
If you don't control the code that calls into the recursion, wrap the recursive call into a new function that catches and reports the StackOverflowError.
You'll often want to create a trace of values from each recursion level. It's going to be a very long exception message, and it's going to be complicated since you want to start reporting back as deep down in the stack as possible without overflowing the stack with your reporting machinery.
I tried to write a recipe here, but it became too complicated, so it's going to be a library for Maven Central I guess.
